# An analogy for qubits and quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I have understood that qubits are special ways to store data where they exist in more than the conventional 2 states. However, I do not understand how they are read, interpreted and manipulated despite reading quite a few articles.

Is there possibly a good analogy to explain how they can potentially speed up calculations?

[There is also a video on youtube by Veritasium](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_IaVepNDT4)  where they explain why it is not necessary that quantum computers reach an answer more quickly as compared to conventional ones? Could somebody throw some light on that too?

Comment: Analogies (to classical physics, I presume) in quantum mechanics are *inevitably* misleading about crucial aspects. Try to get comfortable with the quantum theory *without* analogies instead.

Comment: A quantum computer is basically just a parallel computer that has a computing power that scales with $O(2^n)$ instead of $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of computing elements. Since this means that a quantum computer smaller than a grain of sand could be faster than a machine the size of the universe, we can pretty much take for granted that there is a physical limit somewhere that restricts these architectures to far less than their naive theoretical capability. I would bet some money on quantum computing finding new physics rather than delivering actually fully working machines.